# How are requests routed between two Cloud Run services (frontend and backend) without a load balancer?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run

I have a setup where I have two Cloud Run services deployed on the Google Cloud Platform: one for the front-end of my application developed in React, and another for the backend developed in Java. I'm trying to understand how the requests are routed between these services when no load balancer is involved.

Specifically, when a user interacts with the application, I want to know:

- Do the requests from the frontend service go to the backend service
  through the front-end, or do they go directly to the backend service
  without the front-end?
- If the requests go through the front-end, can    I restrict my
  backend to talk only with frontend not the public?

Could someone explain the routing mechanism for requests between Cloud Run (Frontend and backend) services without a load balancer?

Thank you!

Comment: There is no preconfigured routing for Cloud Run services. You are provided a URL. Your code determines what happens with requests to those URLs.

Answer (score 0):

Without using any intermediary components, the frontend service can send HTTP requests directly  to the backend service.
Please consider the official [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/tutorials/secure-services)  deploying two services to Cloud Run which interact  without a load balancer.

> how to create a secure two-service application running on Cloud Run. This application is a Markdown editor which includes a public "frontend" service which anyone can use to compose markdown text, and a private "backend" service which renders Markdown text to HTML.

In this scenario, the frontend service would have the URL of the backend service's URL and may make requests to the backend using that URL.

You can set up an API gateway,  you can configure it to restrict communication between the frontend and backend services. Check this stackoverflow [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62922369/how-to-hide-my-public-microservices-from-everyone-except-the-api-gateway) by guillaume blaquiere